# Linked List K Alternate Reverse Program

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Can Anyone Explain me why the function *kAltReverse return node type prev and how it will work when you call node->next in print function to get the next element from the struct node & print and how it points to next data?

I don't understand how the data is printed using just prev in *kAltReverse function?

Help is very very highly appreciated!!!

Question Source: GeeksforGeeks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 

struct node {
int data;
struct node* next; };   

struct node *kAltReverse(struct node *head, int k) {
    struct node* current = head;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev = NULL;
    int count = 0;   

    while (current != NULL && count < k)
    {
      next  = current->next;
      current->next = prev;
      prev = current;
      current = next;
      count++;
    }


   if(head != NULL)
      head->next = current;   

   count = 0;
   while(count < k-1 && current != NULL )
   {
      current = current->next;
      count++;
   }


   if(current !=  NULL)
       current->next = kAltReverse(current->next, k); 

   return prev; 
}

void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data) {
   struct node* new_node =
        (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);    
    (*head_ref)    = new_node; 
}   

void printList(struct node *node) {
int count = 0;
while(node != NULL)
{
    printf("%d  ", node->data);
    node = node->next;
    count++;
} 
}       

int main(void) {
struct node* head = NULL;

for(int i = 20; i > 0; i--)
  push(&head, i);

 printf("\n Given linked list \n");
 printList(head);
 head = kAltReverse(head, 3);

 printf("\n Modified Linked list \n");
 printList(head);

 getchar();
 return(0); 
 }
```

Comment: From what I understand from the code, the function is reversing the linked list (or, at least reversing 'k' elements). Basically in the while loop, the current node is filled with the next element, and the current node is saved in the `prev`. So, when you finish reversing all elements the value in prev will be your new head. (I'm not entirely sure on what I've said, but it seems to me that is what the code is doing)

Comment: It looks like a program to reverse 1st k elements of the linked list.

Comment: A debugger is great to understand what does happen... Current program reverse k first elements of the linked list, then advances k position and recurses from there. At the end you have k elements reversed, k in order, k reversed, ... until the end of the list.

Comment: If there more elements on list than *k* it will leak them, right?

Comment: this code works , it reverses alternate group of 3 nodes, and all you want to know is how it works by returning prev from kAltReverse function?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a problem with `int count = 0;`. 
It should be `static int count = 0;`, otherwise it would not behave as expected.

This reverses 1st 'k' elements of the linked list using recursion. Its like in 1st iteration of the loop, the 1st element will be placed at Kth position and 2nd element at 1st position, and in next iteration, with k reduced by 1, it will placed the 2nd value(the current 1st value after iteration) to the (k-1)th position (last position for current iteration). This goes on till count reaches to 'k'.

Comment: There is no problem with `int count = 0`. Why do you want to make it static?